# empty Recyclerview firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I have a problem with my `RecyclerView`. In summary, I put a RecyclerView connected to my database. Then when I start the activity the list is empty.

```
public static class Chartviewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    View mView;
    public Chartviewholder(View itemView){
        super(itemView);
        mView = itemView;
    }
    public void setTitleProduct(String title){
        TextView post_title = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.tvProductName);
        post_title.setText(title);
    }
    public void setImgProduct(String desc){
        ImageView post_desc = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.productIV);
        Picasso.get().load(desc).into(post_desc);
    }
    public void setPriceProduct( String price){
        TextView post_image = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.tvProductPrice);
        post_image.setText(price);
    }
    public void setDescProduct(String desc){
        TextView post_desc=(TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.tvProductDesc);
        post_desc.setText(desc);
    }



}
```

this is my code in the mainclass exactly in the methode OnCreate

```
dbchart = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("product");
    dbchart.keepSynced(true);

    chartrv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.chartrv);

    DatabaseReference personsRef2 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("product");
    Query personsQuery2 = personsRef2.orderByKey();

    chartrv.hasFixedSize();
    chartrv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    FirebaseRecyclerOptions personsOptions2 = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Product>().setQuery(personsQuery2, Product.class).build();

    chartAdapter=new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Product, Chartviewholder>(personsOptions2) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final Chartviewholder holder, int position, @NonNull final Product model) {
            holder.setTitleProduct(model.product_name.toString());
            holder.setImgProduct(model.product_image.toString());
            holder.setDescProduct(model.Product_desc.toString());
            holder.setPriceProduct(Integer.toString(model.product_price)+" DH");
            Button cart=findViewById(R.id.button15);
            cart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    addorder(model);
                }
            });

        }


        @NonNull
        @Override
        public Chartviewholder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.products_list_item2, parent, false);
            return new Chartviewholder(view);
        }
    };
    chartrv.setAdapter(chartAdapter);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `startListening()` to begin listening for data. From the docs:

> The `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` uses an event listener to monitor changes to the Firebase query. To begin listening for data, call the `startListening()` method. You may want to call this in your `onStart()` method. Make sure you have finished any authentication necessary to read the data before calling startListening() or your query will fail.

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    adapter.startListening();
}
```

More information here:

https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md#using-firebaseui-to-populate-a-recyclerview

Comment: thanks that let the recyclerview work correctly